# Two wheeler LED turn indicator design calculations clarifications

Tags: led, led-driver

This is a continuation of this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661650/led-driver-for-2-wheeler-turn-indicator). I have couple of questions.

In the application example the clock frequency is 763 Hz.

1. May I know this 763 Hz is derived from LED blinking frequency of 1.49 Hz?
2. As designer the input I have will LED blinking frequency. I can't see any equations which relate LED blinking frequency and CR timer.
3. From the LED blinking frequency how to decide how long LED will be on and off?

I am keeping the [datasheet](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/led_driver/bd18327efv-m-e.pdf) link and application circuit again here for reference.

[image]